# Oracle APEX Error: Application ID and current security group ID are not consistent

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When trying to authenticate I always get the following error:

***Application ID and current security group ID are not consistent.***

I get the error when I try to run the following login-function:

```
begin

apex_authentication.login(
    p_username => :P101_USERNAME,
    p_password => :P101_PASSWORD );

end;
```

I try to run the code in the SQL Commands.

Do you have some advice?

Thanks

Comment: Where and when exactly do you see this message?

Comment: I have edited my question. have a look there

Comment: I've never met such error, but I think it could be due to running this procedure in APEX IDE. APEX IDE itself an application, created with Oracle APEX. So, it could be a sort of conlict inside `apex_authentication.login` procedure, when it gets `APP_ID` which it don't expect to get. IDE application is from another workspace (`INTERNAL`, as I understand), where you as a developer have no access. Maybe it is a reason.

Comment: Yes, the SQL workshop is just another apex application, which indeed has another workspace (and workspace = security group). You're not really supposed to run that code in the sql workshop. Why are you trying to execute this code?

Comment: @Tom: I am trying to test my authentification/ login process, which doesn't work so far. I am new to Apex and I was given the task to implement a single sign on with two different applications

Comment: This piece of code is run in the login page. But basically it only executes whatever has been specified as the current authentication scheme (under shared components, security). What is your auth scheme set as? Is it a custom one? If so, code will have been specified to be ran to check the login details. And it is that piece of code you need to run instead of the apex_authenthication.login code.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when running APEX code by user that is not the APEX owning schema.
Also, if you try to run APEX stuff outside APEX application you need to set the state of the database session like it was when run from APEX (see: https://www.talkapex.com/2012/08/how-to-create-apex-session-in-plsql/)